# "Unable to connect to 'IIS Express'." How do I fix this?

Tags: visual-studio, iis-express

I've been trying to fix this for a while. I'm working on a cloud service and for some reason I get an error every time I try to run it. I've done everything I could think of doing.

- I disabled and re-enabled SSL
- I set an iplisten for 0.0.0.0 and made sure my computer wasn't currently using the port the project is using
- I tried deleting applicationhost.config and even the whole .vs folder
- I tried cleaning and rebuilding the project
- In combination with messing with applicationhost.config and installing the .NET framework I needed, I restarted my computer

I'm pretty sure I tried a couple other things but they're slipping my mind at the moment. I'm currently using the following/have the following installed:

- I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Community Edition v16.10.31.321.278
- .NET Core v5.0.0
- .NET Framework 2.0, 3.0, 3.5, and 4.8
- I have "Internet Information Services" and "Internet Information Services Hostable Web Core" enabled in my features tab
- I'm running the latest version of Windows 10, completely up-to-date

The weird thing about all of this is that it works fine on my boyfriend's laptop, who's working with me on the project. I'm not exactly sure where to find the IIS logs either, if anyone knows and could let me know, that'd be very appreciated. I've grown tired of searching post after post to see that nothing helps. I'll upload the error logs later if I'm able to find them.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try to run VS as Administrator ?

I used to have the same issue and find out it was the only way to solve this.